# how to make a tree in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, tree

hey i have a project in codeigniter and i want show the data using tree in view using bootstrap and jquery . my data is like this

```
1
11
12
13
131
132
2
3
4
5
```

i want show that data in view. that data is from database so i want use `foreach` in view to show that data. anyone here how to make that data to show to be a tree, assume the data `length` is the level of tree

```
1           -> level 1
   11       -> level 2
   12       -> level 2
   13
     131    -> level 3
     132
2           -> level 1
3
4
5
```

maybe the data can be shown like a file explorer, i want ask how to make or tutorial. because i'm so confused how to make data shown like that

and here's my code in **Model**

```
    function get_family($id_parent){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->like('id',$id_parent,'after');
    $user = $this->db->get();

    return $user->result_array();
}
```

[image: i want tree minimal like this]

Comment: maybe use this website to create the file / tree structure you are looking for: http://filestructuregenerator.com

Answer (score 0):

At first your sql table `user` should consist at least 3 columns:
`id`, `parent_id`, `name`.

The next I recommend you to create your own library class (ex. Tree_library) in `application/libraries` catalog.

This lib should adhere to basic concepts presented below:

**library class :**

```
class Tree_library {
    private $tree = [];
    private $separator = "-";
    private $output = "";

    public function __construct() {}
    public function build($tree) {}
    public function getTreeAsString(){}

    protected function _recursive_iterator($tree) {}
    protected function _get_childs($parent_id) {}
}
```

In your conroller method you'll be load this lib and pass to the template

**conroller :**

```
$this->load->library('parser');
$this->load->library('Tree_library');

// we gets root users because they have NULL in their parent_id in sql table
$root_users = get_family(NULL);

$this->tree_library->build($root_users);

$data = array(
    'TREE' => $this->tree_library->getTreeAsString()
);

$this->parser->parse('template', $data);
```

**template :**

```
<div class="tree">{TREE}</div>
```